# background property not working in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3, scss-lint

Background properties are somehow not working inside my scss file, all other properties do work.

when i use this for example

scss file:

```
body {
  background: #202020;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

browser never returns background (i tested this with different elements and files):

```
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

I use the standard Vue installation which is suitable with scss/css/sass

I include my scss files inside my main.js file like this

```
import './assets/scss/main.scss'
```

I also tried using it inside a scoped tag

```
<style lang="scss" scoped> 
  .layout { background: red; height: 100vh; } 
</style>
```

but only the height applied

import inside style tag doesn't work either

```
<style lang="scss">
@import "../assets/scss/main.scss";
</style>
```

I know it sounds like a stupid typo or something but i can assure you it's not.

Comment: It should work. Did you build it - `npm run build`?

Comment: No, but that's only necessary if you want to go production right? Will try it anyway. Nope still not working

Comment: Hi the font-size works?, are you runing vue in development mode ´npm run serve´ If font-size works, are you sure that comes from your scss file?

Comment: Yes the font-size works, i run in dev mode, not anymore, i just tried to apply background inside a scoped style tag like this: 
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.layout {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}
</style> and only the height applied

Comment: If you remove the height property, is removed in the browser?

Comment: yes, its completely removed

Comment: so... ok.. we can say the file imports works, and also the style tag too.
Can you use 
background-color:#000000; font-size:60px; width: 300px; height: 300px , I need to know if it is a problem specific for background or the file or what

Comment: All the styles except for background-color got applied again. Maybe i turned this off in chrome, doesn't seem possible, its not working in microsoft edge either